# FuelUX DataGrid component with LIMIT SQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, datagrid, fuelux

I'm loading some data with Ajax into FuelUX DataGrid. The problem is that i have a lot of rows in my database and I can't load all the rows at once.
How can I load rows in my FuelUX DataGrid using LIMIT in the query so I can load the information in the moment?. For example I have a query that returns 100 rows and I show 10 items at once in my FuelUX with 10 pages, but i need to query the items by 10, but in the DataGrid show that I have 100 registers.